# Issue with summing over map closure

Tags: rust, iterator, closures

I'm working on AoC to learn Rust and have been trying to cobble together a solution based on what I've seen more experienced rust programmers write.
Below seems to compile entirely except I have an issue with the .sum(). The compiler states that `Iterator::Item` changed to `Result<usize, _>` just before the sum operation.

I don't know how I wouldn't use a Result type from `get_priority` though. As far as I can tell sum works on iterators but it doesn't see the result type as being an iterator?

```
fn main() {
    
    let data = fs::read_to_string("data/data.txt").expect("File should exist");
    let lines = data.lines(); // this is an iterator of lines (type &str)

    let result: usize = lines.map(|rucksack| {
        let (cmprt1, cmprt2) = rucksack.split_at(rucksack.len() / 2);
        let cmprt1: ByteSet = cmprt1.into();
        let cmprt2: ByteSet = cmprt2.into();
        let dup = cmprt1.intersection(cmprt2).first().ok_or("Error finding intersection")?;
        Ok(get_priorty(dup)?)
    }).sum();    
    println!("{}", result)
}

fn get_priorty(letter: u8) -> Result<usize, Box<dyn Error>>{
    match letter {
        b'a'..=b'z' => Ok(1 - (letter + b'a') as usize),
        b'A'..=b'Z' => Ok(27 - (letter + b'A') as usize),
        _ => Err("Unexpected character in rucksack".into())
    }
}
```

The error message

```
10   |       let result: usize = lines.map(|rucksack| {
     |  _______________________________^
11   | |         let (cmprt1, cmprt2) = rucksack.split_at(rucksack.len() / 2);
12   | |         let cmprt1: ByteSet = cmprt1.into();
13   | |         let cmprt2: ByteSet = cmprt2.into();
14   | |         let dup = cmprt1.intersection(cmprt2).first().ok_or("Error finding intersection")?;
15   | |         Ok(get_priorty(dup)?)
16   | |     }).sum();    
     | |______^ `Iterator::Item` changed to `Result<usize, _>` here
note: required by a bound in `std::iter::Iterator::sum`
```

Comment: `map` returns an `Iterator` for items of type `Result<usize, _>`, because that's what you return with `Ok(..)`. You could `collect` it to a vector like `.collect::<Result<Vec<usize>, _>>()?`, but since you want to aggregate it you have to iterate it again (ex. `.collect::<Result<Vec<usize>, _>>()?.iter().sum()`). I'm no sure if you're ok with latter. Hope it helped to get an idea, and hope others can suggest how to make it without iterating the values twice.

Comment: That still throws errors for me, the `?` causes a compilation error on a function not returning result.
Perhaps you could explain why this persons solution (I mostly copied from) doesn't need these extra steps 
https://github.com/niklasha/adventofcode2022/blob/main/src/day03.rs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're summing items of type `Result<usize, E>` you get a result of the same type. But here you try to force the result to a plain `usize`. You need to either:

- Give the correct type `let result: Result<usize, Box<dyn Error>> = lines.map(|rucksack| { … }).sum();`
- Remove the type annotation and let the compiler infer the correct type: `let result = lines.map(|rucksack| { … }).sum();`
- Or handle the error: `let result: usize = lines.map(|rucksack| { … }).sum().unwrap();`

Comment: TIL that `Result` implements `Sum`.

Answer (score 4):

Since your mapping function is fallible, you need a way to fallibly aggregate. You can use [`Iterator::try_fold`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.try_fold) to do this. In your case, instead of `.sum()` you would do `.try_fold(0, |a, b| a + b)`, which will return `Result<usize, Box<dyn Error>>`. If the mapping function returns `Err`, then `try_fold` will propagate that error, otherwise it will return `Ok` with the sum.